# Ataque DDoS en ExpressJS

Tags: nodejs, express

En los ultimos dias estoy recibiendo ataques DDoS en mi VPS, tengo una API con ExpressJS, he añadido el modulo ddos que bloquea cuando recibe peticiones seguidas de una misma IP pero sigo recibiendo peticiones de distintas IP y no se como detenerlo.

Las peticiones son como las siguientes

```
0|SERVIDOR  | ::ffff:107.160.240.188 - - [27/Sep/2018:18:41:16 +0000] "GET http://www.jueaivip.cn HTTP/1.1" 403 -
0|SERVIDOR  | ::ffff:107.151.202.81 - - [27/Sep/2018:18:41:16 +0000] "GET http://www.szgt17.com/ HTTP/1.1" 403 -
```

Estas URLs ni siquiera existen en mi servidor.

Las peticiones validas son asi:

```
0|SERVIDOR  | ::ffff:88.13.250.136 - - [27/Sep/2018:18:41:16 +0000] "GET /api/get/343304344 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: Dificilmente lo vas a detener. ¿ Como vas a forzar a otra máquina a hacer lo que tu quieras ? Puedes ignorarlas en `Express`, o ignorarlas a nivel de cortafuegos (depende del S.O.). O hablar con los *admins* de tu proveedor para que las bloqueen en algún router u otro dispositivo. Ignorarlas hasta que el *atacante* se aburra y te deje tranquilo :-)

Comment: ¿como podría ignorarlas en `Express`?

Answer (score 2):

Existe una "herramienta" o "servicio" muy útil para tu caso: [**CloudFlare**](https://www.cloudflare.com/ddos/)

Puedes crear una cuenta totalmente gratuita para tu **API**, de esta manera también proteges la dirección IP original de tu servidor, ya que **CloudFlare** funciona como Proxy intermediario.